# VBA to Divide Every Other Column by a Constant

Tags: excel, vba

I'm interested in modifying the code below so that it divides the values of every other column by 100 instead of a fixed column X. I know this is probably possible by using a counter and incrementing it by 2 in a while loop, but I'm having trouble with replacing the column X references with an integer:

```
Sub Divide()

Dim element As Range
Dim MaxRows As Long

With Worksheets("Returns")
    MaxRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For Each element In Worksheets("Returns").Range("X1:X" & MaxRows)
    If IsNumeric(element.Value) Then
        element.Value = element.Value / 100
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a loop is definitely the way to go:

```
Sub Divide()
    Dim element As Range
    Dim MaxRows As Long
    Dim col As Long

    With Worksheets("Returns")
        For col = 2 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            MaxRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
            'Use the "Range(cell reference, cell reference)" syntax to define the range
            For Each element In .Range(.Cells(1, col), .Cells(MaxRows, col))
                If IsNumeric(element.Value) Then
                    element.Value = element.Value / 100
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

---

An alternate method of doing the division might be to do a Copy / PasteSpecial-Values-Divide, but that would require you to place a `100` into a dummy cell somewhere first.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer might work, but this is more similar to your original code.

```
Sub Divide()

    Dim element As Range
    Dim MaxRows As Long

    With Worksheets("Returns")
        MaxRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim holdRange as Range
    Dim i as Integer
    i = MaxRows
    While i > 0
        If IsNumeric(Worksheets("Returns").Range("X1:X" & i)) Then
            Worksheets("Returns").Range("X1:X" & i).Value = Worksheets("Returns").Range("X1:X" & i).Value / 100
        End If
    i = i - 2
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: That is changing every 2nd row in column X, not every second column instead of a fixed column X.  The OP seems to want to change every row in columns X and Z (and probably B and D and F, etc).  (Unless I have read the question completely wrong - which is quite possible - I have only just started drinking my morning coffee!)

Answer (score 0):

```
{Sub example()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Application.Selection
        
    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Value = cell.Value / 1000
    Next cell
End Sub}
```